# Does timeout parameter work in angular when using $resource?

Tags: angularjs, resources, timeout

I tried very hard but I could not get it to work. Here is the jsfiddle link. 
http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/qL8bqhdr/

```
    httpRequest = $resource('/echo/json/ ', {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false,
            timeout: timeout.promise
            //timeout: $scope.timeout * 1000
        },
            'options': {
            stripTrailingSlashes: false
        }
    });
```

I am using chrome browser as there may be issues with the trailing slashes in Firefox.

I tried with timeout : milliseconds value and also timeout: promise.
I tried with different versions of $resource but no luck.

I did get it working when using $http and this is the jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/2t346509/

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the correct way:

```
httpRequest = $resource('/echo/json/ ', {}, {
    'query': {
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: false,
        timeout: timeout.promise
        //timeout: $scope.timeout * 1000
    },
    {
        stripTrailingSlashes: false
    }
});
```

You shouldn't add `option: {}`. Just send the object as a parameter.